# How to set random_state in networkx graph with holoviews/bokeh?

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh, holoviews

I would like to generate reproducible plots. With `networkx` is possible to pass the random state to the layout. That is to ensure the plot is the same. When doing the same with holoviews I am getting an error.

```
%pylab inline

import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import holoviews as hv

# generating the graph
G = nx.Graph()
ndxs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
G.add_nodes_from(ndxs)
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,0), (1,3,1), (1,4,-1),
                           (2,4,1), (2,3,-1), (3,4,10)]) 

# drawing with networkx
nx.draw(G, nx.spring_layout(G, random_state=100))


# drawing with holoviews/bokeh
hv.extension('bokeh')
%opts Graph [width=400 height=400]
layout = nx.layout.spring_layout(G, random_state=100)
hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, layout)
>>> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that the `Graph.from_networkx` method accepts the layout function not the dictionary that is output by that function. If you want to pass arguments to the function you can do so as keyword argument, e.g.:

```
hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.spring_layout, random_state=42)
```

In my version of networkx `random_state` is not an accepted argument to the layout functions in which case you can set the seed directly with NumPy:

```
np.random.seed(42)
hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.spring_layout)
```